# How to save several input data in single MySql column?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How to save several input data in single MySql column?

> I have 3 input fields, with same name (name="type"). Now I want to
>   save these 3 input fields datas in one, single Mysql column. How can I
>   solve this?

```
  <div class="form-column col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type"  id="height" placeholder="height (cm)">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type" id="width" placeholder="width (cm)">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type" id="length" placeholder="length (cm)">
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: `serialize()` ???? or if u are asking input field then `name="type[]`

Comment: don't - it'll make running queries on any given dimension an absolute bum (<- polite version).

Comment: did u checked the solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form >
 <div class="form-column col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type[width]"  id="height" placeholder="height (cm)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type[height]" id="width" placeholder="width (cm)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type[length]" id="length" placeholder="length (cm)">
  </div>
```

**Note** when naming the variable in html use specifically `name="type[width]"`. do not use the single or double quote inside with `width` like names

**PHP**

```
<pre>
 <?php  


     $type = $_GET['type'];
     print_r($type);
     extract($type);

        echo 'width:' . $width .'<br />';
        echo 'height:' . $height .'<br />';
        echo 'length:' . $length .'<br />';


   //serialize before inserting
   $mysql_value = serialize($type);
   echo $mysql_value;

   //retrive by unserialize
   $unserialize_mysql_value = unserialize($mysql_value);
   print_r($unserialize_mysql_value);


    ?></pre>
```

**Documentation of [extract](https://www.php.net/extract) function**

[image: Output If Need Clarification ask simply]

Comment: looks like copied the complete the suggestion from other answer :)

Comment: Your Welcome Bro. @devpro and yes please read the answer with open eyes and OPEN MIND

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend it, but you could create an assoc array with the names and values and save it as a JSON string in the database using `json_encode()`. Then you can use `json_decode()` to get the array again and have access each field individually.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name from `name="type"` to `name="type[]"` and the data will POST as an array.

When handling the request body, you can concatenate these however you'd like to be stored.

ex: `$column_val = $request->type[0] . $request->type[1];`

or: `$column_val = implode('-', $request->type);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use same name for multiple input, if you want to use same name then you can use name attribute like an array, something like:

```
name="type[]"
```

Now, you can use [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) method in PHP to store all inputs in one single column something like:

```
$inputData = serialize($_POST['name']); // this will store your array as a string
```

After this, when you need to display this column then you can use [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) method like:

```
$fetchData = unserialize(your column name);
```

Here, `$fetchData` will return the original array, which you saved in your database.

**Additional Point:**

You can also store your input with associative array like:

`name="type[width]"` and `name="type[height]"` and `name="type[length]"`